# Rename page with Apollo & Vue router

Tags: vue.js, graphql, vue-router, apollo

I'd like to rename the title of the pages depending on the data received by Apollo.
[image: Tab names]

For example, at the url `myproject.com/media/title1`, my GraphQL reply will be:

```
{
  "data": {
    "creation":
      {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Title1",
        "creationDate": "2019-09-22 07:37:57 UTC",
        "coverUrl": "linktomedia.com/image.jpg",
      }
  }
}
```

I want to get the title in `data -> creation -> title` as my title page name.

How can I do this ?

Thank you.

Comment: try this one after you fetched your data document.title = data.creation.title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vue-apollo` smart queries provide a `result` callback that's called when the query completes. You can complete any actions that depend on the data, including changing the title, inside the callback. Something like:

```
apollo: {
  creation: {
    query: YOUR_QUERY,
    result: ({ data }) => {
      document.title = data.creation.title
    },
  }
}
```